# mariadb.service - linking unit aliases mysql.service & mysqld.service - (why) is it necessary

Tags: debian, symlink, services, mariadb

I cannot find the originally site I found how to set up MariaDB on linux.

Dependend on that tutorial I wrote an ansible playbook. While refactoring my playbooks I found those two tasks.

```
- name: SymLinking the service unit alias `mysql.service` to `mariadb.service`
  file:
    src: "/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service"
    dest: "/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service"
    state: link
    force: yes

- name: SymLinking the service unit alias `mysqld.service` to `mariadb.service`
  file:
    src: "/etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service"
    dest: "/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service"
    state: link
    force: yes
```

`systemctl status` on all 3 services ( `mariadb.service`, `mysql.service`, `mysqld.service`) now states the same main PID for all processes.

So while it's obious that symlinked service units are referencing the same process I can only assume these services has to be created for downward compatibility.

But while it's 2019 my questions are

- Is that linking still necessary?
- If yes, do I need both `mysql` **and** `mysqld`?
- If not, in which probable cases I should expect problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried out now by commenting out the mentioned lines above. So I found out the package `mariadb-server` is creating that links by itself. So linking that service files I don't have to take care about.